# Get all the text of the current node only

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is my XML:

```
<section>
  <para>part1 <breakline/> part2
    <list>
      <para>list1 </para>
      <para>list2 </para>
    </list> 
  </para>
<para>before_line_break <breakline/> after</para>
<para>para3</para>
</section>
```

Expected output:

```
part1 
part2
before_line_break 
after
para3
```

I want "part2" but not "list1" and "list2"

An equivalent HTML file would be:

```
<html>
  <body>
    part1 <br/>
    part2 <br/>
    before_line_break <br/>
    after <br/>
    para3 <br/>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried many things in my xsl file. Here is just an example (that doesn't work of course):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
  <body>
    <xsl:for-each select="section/para">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <br/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How should I change my XSL file to get the expected output?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What output are you currently getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take this just as starting point:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="section/para"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="para">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="text()|breakline"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <!-- print br if text() is at end of para -->
        <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
            <br/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- replace breakline with br -->
    <xsl:template match="breakline">
        <br/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- mute list -->
    <xsl:template match="list/para"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: As a newbie in XML/XSL, I really appreciate you help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is probably the shortest possible solution -- only two templates, no conditionals, no `xsl:for-each`:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <html>
   <body>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="para/text()[normalize-space()]"/>
   </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>    
 <xsl:template match="para/text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xA;', normalize-space(.))"/><br />
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<section>
  <para>part1 <breakline/> part2
    <list>
      <para>list1 </para>
      <para>list2 </para>
    </list>
  </para>
<para>before_line_break <breakline/> after</para>
<para>para3</para>
</section>
```

**the wanted correct result is produced:**

```
<html>
   <body>
      part1<br>
      part2<br>
      before_line_break<br>
      after<br>
      para3<br>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this other solution. This is amazing how we can get the same result in different ways.

Comment: Just a comment: the '&#xA;' is not necessary. A simple space ' ' is enough.

Comment: @DelrocqLaurent: For the purposes of seeing the result displayed in a browser we don't need a NL. However I wanted to make the output look as close as possible to the one provided in your question. As for the different solutions, my recommendation is to always choose and use the shortest one -- the one with least moving parts is least error-prone and most maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/section">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="para/text()">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          <br/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It almost works: With this code, I get an empty line after "part2" due to the (empty) text after the list.